# Error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 argument

Tags: c++

When I try the below program its gives me the :error C2064:  I tried in google but not able to find the exact reason. Please help.

```
class myClass 
{
    public:
        void function(myClass dTemp)
        {
            cout<<"Inside myClass: taking myClass parameter"<<endl;
        }
};
```

.

```
int main()
{

    myClass myClassTemp;
    myClass myClassTemp1;

    myClassTemp(myClassTemp1);// error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 argument.

return 0;
};
```

Comment: listen to the compiler, it tells you don't have a function call

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you mean to be able to call an object of type `myClass` like a function? You need to overload `operator()` for that:

```
void operator()(myClass dTemp){
  // ...
}
```

If you instead wanted to call the function, well, you should actually do so:

```
myClassTemp.function(myClassTemp1);
```

Comment: It is really my mistake.. my intention was to call the function(myClassTemp1). OOOPssss!!!!

Answer (score 5):

You should include your function name when calling.

```
myClassTemp.function(myClassTemp1)
```

Or if your intention is functor object do it following way:

```
class myClass 
{
    public:
        void operator() (myClass dTemp)
        {
            cout<<"Inside myClass: taking myClass parameter"<<endl;
        }
};

. 
int main()
{

    myClass myClassTemp;
    myClass myClassTemp1;

    myClassTemp(myClassTemp1);

return 0;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

This should be

```
//          vvvvvvvv
myClassTemp.function(myClassTemp1);
```